# Two entities in one dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have two entites with association. I create a dataGridView by drag and drop from objects Data Source and manually binding from to list. Everything works fine with one entity. Is there any possibility of create one dataGridView with two entities(Zamow and ZamSkany) by drag and drop + manually filling? I can do this by view (on SQL side) but in same cases I'd like to have other possibilities.

```
 pg = new PGEntities();
 BindingList<Zamow> myList;
 var query = (from zam in pg.Zamow where zam.Rok == 2012 select zam).Take(100);
 MyList = new BindingList<Zamow>(query.ToList());
 zamowBindingSource.DataSource = MyList;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try to create `Class`, let say a `ViewZamowAndSamSkany`

```
public class ViewZamowAndSamSkany
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Proforma { get; set; }
    //and Others Properties
}
```

and now, rebuild your project and from the `Objects Data Source` add the `ViewZamowAndSamSkany` then drag-drop to your `Form` as a `DataGridView` and you can apply the linq-entites `inner join`

```
var query = (from zam in pg.Zamow 
             join skany in zam.NUMBER equals skany.NUMBER
             where zam.Rok == 2012 
             select new ViewZamowAndSamSkany
             {
                 Data = zam.Data,
                 Proforma = zam.Proforma
             }).Take(100);

MyList = new BindingList<ViewZamowAndSamSkany>(query.ToList());
zamowBindingSource.DataSource = MyList;
```