# How do I SaveChanges on a joined view of 2 or more tables using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-4

In order to get practice with Entity Framework, I am creating a C# WinForms project, and I used the answer to the question in this link to join and display tables in a datagridview:

> [Two entities in one dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835217/two-entities-in-one-datagridview)

I have searched for a clean way to save (to the SQL Server database) the changes made in the datagridview. Is there a good, fast, short, clean way? I have seen some ugly attempts, and even if they work, I am turned off by their ugliness.

With one table only (no joins), calling .SaveChanges works fine.

Here is the class set up to hold the joined fields:

```
public class CustAndOrders
{
    // Customer table
    public Int64 Cust_Id { get; set; }
    public string Cust_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Cust_BDay { get; set; }

    //Order table
    public Int64 Order_Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Order_Amt { get; set; }
    public DateTime Order_Date { get; set; }

    // OrderDetail table
    public Int64 Item_Number { get; set; }
    public decimal Item_Amt { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code to display the joined info in a datagridview. Obviously, the SaveChanges call does not work...yet

```
  AWModel.TestJLEntities dc;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dc = new AWModel.TestJLEntities();

        var query = from c in dc.Customers
                    join o in dc.Orders on c.CustId equals o.CustId
                    join od in dc.OrderDetails on o.OrderId equals od.OrderId
                    orderby o.OrderDate ascending, c.CustId, o.OrderAmount
                    select new CustAndOrders
                    {
                        Cust_Id = c.CustId,
                        Cust_Name = c.CustName,
                        Cust_BDay = c.CustBday,
                        Order_Id = o.OrderId,
                        Order_Amt = o.OrderAmount,
                        Order_Date = o.OrderDate,
                        Item_Number = od.ItemNumber,
                        Item_Amt = od.ItemAmount
                    };
        var users = query.ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error saving changes");
        }
    }
```

Comment: JLee - did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is not seeing your changes because your data grid view is not bound to the EF entities, but rather an object populated from it's entities:

```
select new CustAndOrders
    {
        Cust_Id = c.CustId,
        Cust_Name = c.CustName,
        Cust_BDay = c.CustBday,
        Order_Id = o.OrderId,
        Order_Amt = o.OrderAmount,
        Order_Date = o.OrderDate,
        Item_Number = od.ItemNumber,
        Item_Amt = od.ItemAmount
    };
```

One solution I can think of is to compose CustAndOrders of the entities themselves:

```
public class CustAndOrders
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public OrderDetail OrderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

And then bind to those fields i.e.

```
{Binding Customer.CustId}
```

Or if you don't want to change your bindings then pass the EF entities into the CustAndOrders object and in your properties just get and set from the entities:

```
public class CustAndOrders
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public OrderDetail OrderDetail { get; set; }

    // Customer table
    public Int64 Cust_Id
    {
        get
        { return Customer.CustId;}
        set
        { Customer.CustId = value; }
    }
... Do this for the rest of your properties
```

And then query looks like this:

```
var query = from c in dc.Customers
                join o in dc.Orders on c.CustId equals o.CustId
                join od in dc.OrderDetails on o.OrderId equals od.OrderId
                orderby o.OrderDate ascending, c.CustId, o.OrderAmount
                select new CustAndOrders { Customer = c, Order = o, OrderDetail = od };
```

Comment: thank you eric. i will try this today and let you know.

Comment: i tried both methods, but i cannot seem to get a handle on this. what does the query look like? i should have posted an even more simple example, with 2 fields total, one from each of 2 tables, because i want to see the totality of it working, and then look at it to gain understanding of how it works. The first method using binding seems harder for me to understand because I am not sure how to bind fields to the dgv.

Comment: Since it seems you are letting the DataGridView dynamically generate the columns and bindings then use the second method. I added the query. It's important to understand why your original solution isn't working though - it is because your anonymous object is not the returned EF entity but rather an anonymous object with a copy of the entities values. HTH

Comment: Yes, I got that from your first post. Thx for the explanation. It makes sense. Also, I had already created the CustAndOrders class exactly as you did above, but I just now added the query select clause, and I get the error: "Only parameterless constructors are supported in LINQ to entities." on the query.ToList() line.

Comment: Ok, it'll be a bit ugly but rather than pass the entities in the constructor you can expose the _xxx properties as public and assign them like in the original query.

Comment: Or define the columns in your DatGridView and change the bindings like in the first part of my answer. Thinking about it you don't even need the CustAndOrders class, just compose the anonymous class of the Customer, Order and OrderDetails entities.

Comment: i appreciate your help, but it won't compile after i added your updates to this line:      "select new CustAndOrders { Customer = c, Order = o, OrderDetail = od };"     at this point, i just really want to see the complete code for a full working example with one field from one table and one field from another table

Comment: Did you also add the changes I made to the CustAndOrders class?

Comment: Oh, ok. I just added those changes and it works fine! Thank you Eric. Accepted answer!

Comment: However, I don't understand the part: "Thinking about it you don't even need the CustAndOrders class, just compose the anonymous class of the Customer, Order and OrderDetails entities."

Comment: Yes, right now I assume you are having the DataGridView automatically generate the columns for you. This is why you need the CustAndOrders class - to instruct the auto generation what the columns should be. If you were to explicitly define the column and bindings yourself then you could just return an anonymous type with Customer, Order and OrderDetails properties.