# Most effective way to combine two entities and display in a data grid

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datagridview

A similar question was asked before by some other member and and an answered here --> [Two entities in one dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835217/two-entities-in-one-datagridview)

Dear senior devs, please correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't shake the feeling that there might be a better/more efficient way to do it.

Lets say I have two Entities(tables) - Case and Session

Case Entity

```
CaseId
CaseName
```

Sesssion Entity

```
SessionId
CaseId
SessionDate
```

Now I want to show SessionId,SessionDate and CaseName in a Data Grid. What is the most effective way of doing this? I also saw a suggestion to create a View in the SQL server and import it to the DataModel. If that is the approach I sould take, what would my SQL Server View query look like?

Answer (score 1):

I would always do this in SQL, and usually would use a stored proc to return the data and populate a datatable, and use that datatable in my code. The SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT      S.SessionID     , 
            S.SessionDate   ,
            C.CaseName
FROM        [Case]          AS  C
INNER JOIN  [Session]       AS  S   ON C.CaseId = S.CaseId;
```

You will need to decide if the inner join is correct: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thank you for answering promptly. However, can I map this as an Entity? Can I use a SQL View instead?

Comment: Yes - I guess, how you get the information isn't really much concern to the application, so long as you are passing it what it expects. You would need to create your view, the code above could be used for that, and then execute SELECT [columns] FROM [YourView] in the application. Looking at the link you posted, by 'Entity' are you refering to a class, or model, that represents the data you will be returning form the view? If so,  is there a specific part of the process you are having issues with?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework to create Entities from the database. I only use Linq queries in the application. I heard it's bad practice to write SQL straight in the application. So I'm using Repository pattern with Linq.

Comment: Ah I see, entity framework is not something I have any familiarity of. Will let someone else advise. Sorry I can't be of more assistance. You are right however, writing SQL in the application is not ideal, and can leave you open to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts! I appreciate it!